# Android. Empty ListView. Custom message. Very confusing behavior, can't make sense of it

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` (part of a `ListFragment`), and I noticed that when the list is empty, the message below appears (*No matching activities found*).

1. I want to replace that message with a `View`.
2. I've tried `setEmptyView(View emptyView)`.
3. When I do *not* use `setEmptyView`, the message disappears when list is populated (correct, but I still want 1 above).
4. When I use `setEmptyView`, the `emptyView` disappears when list is populated (correct). However, that text message is still there (see figure 1). And worse! Now it doesn't disappear even when list is populated (see figure 2: shouldn't it behave just like on 3?).
5. Where does this message come from? the aether? How do I remove it?!?

[image: Weird ListView caption]

[image]

Comment: By the way, I've posted a similar question yesterday, but I voted it to be removed. It was ambiguous (since I didn't know yet where the problem was). Now I isolated the problem to the ListView: I have nothing else except an empty ListFragment. This question reflects that, while the other did nothing but confuse everyone. This is not about "bumping" (it may appear like such a thing). I thought it'd be better to start from scratch. Thank you and sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue with `ListFragment`. I create a layout with the `ListView` and a `View` (an `ImageView` in my case) with the id: `android:id="@id/android:empty"`, and worked like a charm..

Comment: I see... but I'm looking forward into using all benefits of ListFragment. If you see the `android.R.layout.list_content` layout, there are many elements I want to leverage. I don't want to do everything by hand when the SDK provides the components already...

Comment: Disregard that. I'll try what you suggested and I'll adapt it to my needs. I'll update this later with (I hope) the solution. Thanks!

Comment: googling i found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Comment: Yeah, that will do. Problem is, I was looking at list_content.xml as in v11 SDK. Since it differs a lot between SDK versions, I guess I better forget about it... ;-)